# Install Virtualenv with lower version of python

Tags: virtualenv, python-2.5

i'm using Ubuntu having python version 2.7.5.

I have a virtual-env in which i'm using the python2.7.

Now i need to install set up a another virtual environment with python version 2.5, something like

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.5 envname
```

but the problem is how to install python 2.5 along side 2.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

This format works for me:

```
virtualenv --python=python2.5 envname
```